# Finding a node in a NON binary tree [Java]

Tags: java, loops, recursion, search, tree

I want to find a node of type T that is located somewhere in a **non-binary tree** in Java.

Can it be done both recursively and non recursively?

I thought of applying the rules of binary tree search but without the left and right stuff, but I can't get the idea on how to do it.

Comment: Have you given either a shot yourself? Folks are usually more inclined to help out if they have some example code to work off of. That being said, it can be done both recursively and non-recursively. Instead of thinking about left and right members, think about an array or ArrayList member.

Comment: I'm really not on that level yet, but thanks. I guess I'll need to learn it myself.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect it too be too hard to generalize an algorithm for a binary tree to work for a tree where each node can have many descendants. You will need a loop over those children, of course. Yes, it can be done both recursively and iteratively.

Comment: You don't have to learn it yourself. You have to try, and come back when you have questions about your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if a node in this tree has a fixed number of possible descendants. If it does then you can basically just use the same functions with n more if statements for each possible child. But, if the number of descendants is not fixed then you're dealing with something closer to a graph. In that case you have to use a graph algorithm.

Comment: Even if the amount descendants is not fixed, you can use the same functions.